# I want to get dropdown with selected value (update to angular 10 and above)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, angular10

I am trying to achieve dropdown with first value selected and disable only to show to user.

HTML

```
            <select name="level" [(ngModel)]="level">
                <option disabled [selected]="disabledValue" [value]="disabledValue">{{disabledValue}}</option>
                <option *ngFor="let level of levelKeys" [value]="level">{{level}}</option>
            </select>
```

ts

```
  public disabledValue: string = 'level';
  public level: Level = Level.EMPTY;
```

Level class contain easy normal and hard.

In my user interface he should see level and after click dropdown show him Level class with 3 options

Dropdown look like this ->

```
[level] selected + disabled 
[easy] option 1
[normal] option 2
[hard] option 3
```

Thank for your help guys :-)